# Why my code does not go to the next view

Tags: ios, swift

**No error at debug. The code does not proceed to the next page after the login is accepted... help pls**

```
if (emailValue == userEmail || passValue == userPassword) {

    //store user information in the app to maintain session

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.set(usernameValue, forKey: "usernameValue")
    defaults.set(nameValue, forKey: "nameValue")
    defaults.set(emailValue, forKey: "emailValue")

    // Display Alert Message with confirmation
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: Constants.SucessMessages.EIRP, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: its comes in inside ok action

Comment: @PAB PAB, you want to go to next screen, but the code you have used is for going to previous screen on tap of okAction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to go to next screen, but the code you have used is for going to previous screen on tap of okAction

Assuming name of your destination controller is DestinationViewController and ID used is DestinationVCID, below options can be used to go to next screen depending upon your current usage.

Code has to be used for the UIAlertAction you have used, i.e okAction

**Push**

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVCID") as? DestinationViewController {

        if let navigator = navigationController {
            navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
}
```

**Present**

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVCID") as? DestinationViewController
{
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```